# Inner Join With three table gives error

Tags: join, inner-join

i have three tables named sehirler, ilceler, mahalle. I want to connect these three table to get some related information. I use following query:

```
SELECT sehirler.sehirad,
    sehirler.sehirid,
    ilceler.ilcead,
    ilceler.ilceid,
    ilceler.sehirid,
    mahalle.mahallead,
    mahalle.ilceid
FROM sehirler
INNER JOIN ilceler
    ON sehirler.sehirid = ilceler.sehirid
INNER JOIN mahalle
    ON ilceler.ilceid = mahalle.ilceid
```

and get following error message:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sehirler.sehirid=ilceler.sehirid INNER JOIN mahalle ON ilceler.ilceid= mahalle.ilceid'.

/subs.asp, line 89
```

I couldn't find the mistake, please could you help me. Where am I making mistake?

Table-1: Sehirler has only two columns : sehirid and sehirad
Table-2: ilceler has three columns: ilceid, ilcead, sehirid
Table-3: mahalle has four columns: mahalleid, mahallead, ilceid, sehirid

Comment: Can you improve the layout of your SQL. The error says that there is a syntax error but it's hard to read on see the query.

Comment: Check the last edit Peter Smith

Comment: Why are you still using the JET engine? And why are creating new stuff in classic asp? I don't see anything wrong with your query but you should get in the habit of using aliases.

Comment: For the checking perpose I removed alias, normally I used them. If I remove the third table, it works but when I add the second inner join it gives this error.

Comment: I cannot see anythning obviously wrong. Is it possible that there was a syntax error that relaying out has removed?  The error message says `sehirler.sehirid=ilceler.sehirid INNER JOIN mahalle ON ilceler.ilceid= mahalle.ilceid` is wrong somewhere. It could be local to the JET engine.